# How can I validate array in laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, upload, laravel-5.3, required

My case is like this :

My view :

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'product/store', 'class'=>'form-horizontal', 'method'=>'POST', 'files' => true]) !!}
    ...
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="photo[]" multiple>
    ...
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

My controller :

```
public function store(CreateProductRequest $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
    ...
}
```

I set required here :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
class CreateProductRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'=>'required',
            ...
            'photo[]'=> 'required|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,jpg|max:7024',
        ];
    }
}
```

When the name is array, it does not work

When I click submit, it will back to form add

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: try: `'photo' => 'required', 'photo.*' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,jpg|max:7024',`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are validating an array form field, you may retrieve all of the messages for each of the array elements using the * character:

```
'photo.*' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,jpg|max:7024'
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this. It will work.

```
'photo.*' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,jpg|max:7024'
```

Answer (score 0):

'photo' => 'required|array',
'photo.*' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,jpg|max:7024'

Answer (score 0):

For assoc array like:

```
$skills = [['id'=> 1, 'name' => 'photoshoot', photo => File], ['id'=>2, 'name'=> 'someskill', photo => File]];
```

For validate in DB validation rule will be like this:

```
'skills.*.id' => 'required|exists:skills,id',
'skills.*.photo' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,jpg|max:7024'
```